# How to avoid Video lag when writing using OpenCV2?

Tags: image-processing, video-processing, frame-rate, opencv, python

When I try to simply read and write a video with OpenCV2, it is introducing a 1.033x lag in the video - for eg, an original video of 3:17min becomes 3:24min in the output video, 19:00min becomes 19:38min. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

The FPS (29) and frame count stays the same in input and output videos. (I am trying to do facial recognition but I am trying to figure out the lag first)

```
input_movie = cv2.VideoCapture(video_under_analysis)
length = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
width, height = (
        int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
        int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    )
fps = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
output_movie = cv2.VideoWriter()
output_file_name = "output.mp4"

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
output_movie.open(output_file_name, fourcc, fps, (width, height), True)
frame_number = 0
FRAME_LIMIT = length
while True:
    ret, frame = input_movie.read()
    frame_number += 1
    
    if not ret or frame_number > FRAME_LIMIT:
        break
    
    if frame is not None:
      output_movie.write(frame)

update_progress(1)
output_movie.release()
input_movie.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Whats the `FRAME_LIMIT`? Is it the `length`?

Comment: Yes it is the length, will update the question

Comment: How are you verifying video length?

Comment: I'm checking the frame counts - ```output_movie='output.mp4';
output_movie = cv2.VideoCapture(output_movie);
output_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)``` and I get the same numbers

Comment: I meant how are you verifying the time duration of the video.

Comment: I am simply checking the video lengths directly by opening the files - my inputs are YouTube videos. Also I noticed my lag is always 1.033x, I am not sure how that might be related to the FPS (29) though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue might be in this line

```
fps = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
```

You are converting the `float` value to `int`. Your input video's fps might be some `float` like 29.9 which is converted to 29. Hence, the constant lag.

Comment: MASSIVE overlook! I was almost down to skipping frames to prevent audio lag. Thankyou so much for pointing this out!